# Is there a way to set a default border color/size in CSS?

Tags: html, css, border

I'd like to set a global default size and color for all my borders using css.  I'm having an issue where my css for setting a default border width and color is being overwritten the moment I try and use it.  Basically I have something like this:

My.css

```
* { 
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #222;
}

#streak {
  border-bottom: solid;
}
```

My.html

```
<html>
<div id="streak">
  WOOOOOOOO!
</div>
</html>
```

The problem is that the moment I set the bottom border to solid, it defaults the width to 3px and the color to black.  In the developer console it shows that the css for * {...} was applied, but then it was crossed out and now it is currently at a width and color of initial, which it got from the "border-bottom: solid;" rule.

I've found that if I use !important in the * {...} css rules, it'll work, but I'm really not a fan of using !important if I don't have to.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing with the `*` rule is fine. What you're trying to do on individual elements is set the border style. You will need to use the `border-style` component property for that, rather than the `border` shorthand as the shorthand will override the width and color with their initial values (which are `medium` and `currentColor` respectively):

```
#streak {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
}
```

Of course, this means you can continue using the shorthand in situations where you *do* want to override the global width and color with other values.

Answer (score -1):

your css file and class everything correct.you missed the line "border:solid" this for border style.without giving type it won't work.now you can try with this.

```css
* { 
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #222;
  border:solid
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="example.css"  />
</head>
<div>
  WOOOOOOOO!
</div>
<span> hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii </span>
</html>
```